# Grouping fields of a database

Tags: sql, group-by

I have to perform the following steps:

- I have a database with records containing a lot of personal information about employees `(Name, Surname, City, Region, Address,Bank Number, Bank Name)`
- Group the data where the output is a number of predefined groups in the following format `(Name, Surname); (City,Region, Address); (Bank Number, Bank Name),...`

I don't know a priori the names of the database fields. 
I don't have any idea of how to proceed. Can someone help me?

Comment: What kind of database engine do you use? Generally speaking you should take a look at `GROUP BY` if it's any SQL engines such as MySql or MSSQL.

Comment: I can use SQL if I want. I just need to show an example. Anyway,the problem is that i don't know the name of the fields in the database. So, it should be an automated way. This is the reason why i spoke of clustering.

Comment: I suspect that you have a 'table', with 'columns'. And if you don't know the names of the columns in your table then something is very wrong with your data model